# how to distinguish a feature is continuous or discrete in C4.5 in python and how to deal with discrete feature that may have many values?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

I plan to implement the C4.5 algorithm in python but I have two questions that annoyes me.

First, how to distinguish a feature is continuous or discrete in C4.5 in python as the C4.5 algorithm handles the two type features in different ways ?

I think I can judge the data type of the  feature. That is if the type of the feature is `float` then I know this is a continuous feature, if not, it is a discrete feature.

```
if type(feature) == float:
    this is a continuous feature
else: 
    this is a discrete feature
```

Second, when the feature is a discrete feature and has many values, how should I deal with such features? if I treat it as a discrete feature then the tree will have many branches. For example, the feature is `the number that a word occurs in the trainset`,  it could range from 0 to thousand, so what's the proper way to deal with such features? Should feature discretization be a good option or just treat it as a continuous feature?

Thanks!